# Subtract lives if sprite is touching other sprite?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm making a game where I have a comet and a spaceship. if the spaceship touches a comet, it's minus 1 life, which I've made an SKLabelNode. Can anyone help me figure out how to write this? I've looked online and I can't find any help so I think this is also a good resource for others in my position. I'm using Xcode 7.3 and Swift 3. Thanks!

Comment: show us what you have so far, or what you've tried so far

Comment: In didBeginContact when an appropriate contact is detected, increment lives variable, and update label's text property accordingly (you can do this in didSet observer of the lives variable).

Comment: @Whirlwind Oooh okay I'll give it a go

Comment: @OptimusComposite Here is what I've meant. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34841022